# Issues in getting response of ask permission intent in Dialog flow node js app

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have developed action for english and hindi language. I have asked DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION permission in dialog flow intent. It works perfectly in english. But when i switched to hindi language and ask user location permission, assistance doesn't understand response in hindi. It goes to fallback intent.

[image]

If I respond in english, it works perfectly even if device language is hindi.
Please help.

Comment: Do you have separate code for your english version and hindi version ?

Comment: Nope. I am using i18n for hindi and english version.